Unable to access a partition on a SAS LUN on Windows
Let me start of by saying, I have no clue what I am doing in regards to using this Dell PowerVault MD3400. It was setup long before I arrived at the company and everyone who was involved with the setup is long gone.
We have a Dell PowerVault MD3400 connected to two servers with SAS cables. On the MD3400 is a virtual disk with LUN 1. On the servers connected to the MD3400 we can see the disk as Disk 3 and it has 2 partitions, but the 50 TB partition does not show up as a drive.

We do have a Failover Cluster managing the disks on the MD3400, but it shows disk 3 as a 1 TB drive, not the nearly 50 TBs that it is.

Here are the virtual disks in the MD3400.

How do I access the 50 TB partition?
Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Everything about this system is off topic due to it is end of life years ago, however did you notice the red splat?

Nowhere does the "on-topic" description say the device can't be end-of-life. The device is being used in an enterprise application.

All hardware is eventually rendered junk status and will fail. 15 years is well into that. Neglected systems aren't suitable for this type of forum except as a cautionary tale.

Like it or not legacy systems are part of IT infrastructure everywhere. If you didn't want to be helpful you should have just kept on going and ignored the post.
